# How to two way file transfer with adb on android 5.0?

Tags: android, linux

Is there a way to move a simple text file via adb to a stock (locked) android 5.0 device where it can be seen and opened by a file manager?
For example I can connect to the devices with adb shell make a directory and transfer a file to the device:

```
adb shell
mkdir /data/local/tmp/new
adb push test.txt /data/local/tmp/new
```

But then I can't navigate to test.txt from the device.
I tried setting the permissions to 755.
Is there a way I can access test.txt from a text editor?
(I can copy apps just fine.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all about what folders your file manger has permissions to see.  I'd try putting it in Downloads as a test, it should work there

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that but I think I had the wrong path to Download (adb: error: failed to copy 'feeds.txt' to '/storage/emulated/0/Download': remote Read-only file system ), I poked around some more and found /storage/emulated/legacy/Download/ works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
In adb shell environment, you don't have permissions of the dir "data".

So you can't use command cd by cd to target dir "data->local->tmp->new".

But it still has a way to get, just like the picture shows, just type every thing in cd target, and you will get there!

Comment: You can use command adb pull those files in to your pc